# Difference between collation_server and default charset/collation mysql

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

I'm having some difficulty understanding differences in logic between my.cnf settings and actual database settings.

For example, my my.cnf has the following:

```
init_connect                    = 'SET collation_connection=utf8_unicode_ci'
init_connect                    = 'SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server            = utf8
collation-server                = utf8_unicode_ci
```

And when I log into the database without specify the schema I see the following collation variables set:

```
mysql> show variables like '%coll%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have a few questions here:

1) Why is collation_connection set to utf8_general_ci when I specify utf8_unicode_ci in my my.cnf file?

2) Why, when I create tables is the default collation utf8_general_ci?

I'm having some difficulty understanding how these collation variables are interpreted and used.

Comment: Keep in mind that `root` skips `init_connect` during its login.

Answer (score 3):

Several character set and collation system variables relate to a client's interaction with the server.

The server uses the `character_set_connection` and `collation_connection` system variables, then it converts statements sent by the client from `character_set_client` to `character_set_connection` (*except for string literals that have an introducer such as _latin1 or _utf8*). The `collation_connection` is important **for comparisons of literal strings**. For comparisons of strings with column values, `collation_connection` does not matter because columns have their own collation, which has a **higher collation precedence**.

Regarding your second question - the server character set and collation are used as default values if the database character set and collation **are not specified** in `CREATE DATABASE` statements. **They [have no other purpose](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-server.html).** You have to make sure that your database character set is set at the very creation of it (or, you can change it later of course with `ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach charsets...  (This bypasses the question posed and provides a 'best practice'.)

- When connecting to the database, use the connect parameter(s) of the client to announce *the encoding for bytes in the client*.  Alternatively, execute `SET NAMES` after connecting.
- Be sure that each column has the desired `CHARACTER SET` and, optionally, the desired `COLLATION`.  This establishes *the encoding stored in the columns*. It is usually sufficient to specify these on the `CREATE TABLE` and let the columns inherit it.  (The table defaults to the database, which defaults to `character_set_server`, but it confusing, maybe unwise, to depend on this tree of defaults.)

`SET NAMES` sets exactly these three 'variables':

```
character_set_client
character_set_connection
character_set_results
```

Think of them as saying what encoding exists in the client, regardless of what `CHARACTER SET` exists on each column.  Conversion will occur, as needed, on `INSERT` and `SELECT`.

(This answer should not be in conflict with @bodi0's.)